funcion (array) keyword en php?
Quiero convertir un objeto a un array. He utilizado el (array) keyword. ¿Existe otro método para convertir a array?
$result = (array) $object;


Hola, te sugerimosrevisar [ask],

¿Que has buscado y encontrado, y que error te da?  Se me ocurre que puedas usar json_encode/json_decode, pero para su sintaxis correcta mejor la buscas en php.net y si no lo consigues preguntes de nuevo.

Por el nombre, asumimos que $object es del tipo object, en tal caso, puedes convertirlo a array de varias maneras: 1. Usando get_object_vars(); 2. Con json_decode() y json_enconde(), por ejemplo: json_decode(json_encode($object), true); 3. Creando un nuevo array, recorriendo en un bucle $object y metiendo dentro del nuevo array las propiedades / valores de $object; 4. Cualquier otra forma que te quieras inventar o que alguien se haya inventado, como crear un convertidor personalizado...

Por el nombre, asumimos que $object es del tipo object, en tal caso, puedes convertirlo a array de varias maneras:

Usando get_object_vars(). Te calcará el objeto, aunque tenga niveles de anidamiento.

Con json_decode() y json_enconde(). Te convierte todo a array, sin respetar los tipos anidados. Como podrás observar en la salida, en este caso los objetos anidados son convertidos a simples arrays.

Creando un nuevo array, recorriendo en un bucle $object y metiendo dentro del nuevo array las propiedades / valores de $object. En este caso, tendrás que hacer verificaciones internas, en caso de que $object tenga una estructura compleja.

Cualquier otra forma que te quieras inventar o que alguien se haya inventado, como crear un convertidor personalizado...


Veamos algunos ejemplos:
DEMO
$line=sprintf('%s------------------------%s',PHP_EOL,PHP_EOL);
//Creamos un objeto con varios niveles de anidamiento
$subb=(object) array('subb'=>'foo subb');
$sub=(object) array('a'=>'foo sub','b'=>$subb);
$object = (object) array('1' => 'foo',2=>'bar','3'=>$sub);

printf('%s%s','(object) Objeto inicial',$line);
var_dump($object);

printf('%s%s','(array) Código original',$line);
var_dump((array) $object);

printf('%s%s','get_object_vars',$line);
var_dump(get_object_vars($object));

printf('%s%s','json_decode+json_encode',$line);
var_dump(json_decode(json_encode($object),true));

printf('%s%s','[]',$line);
var_dump([$object]);


Salida:
(object) Objeto inicial
------------------------
object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
  ["1"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  ["2"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  ["3"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(7) "foo sub"
    ["b"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
      ["subb"]=>
      string(8) "foo subb"
    }
  }
}
(array) Código original
------------------------
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(7) "foo sub"
    ["b"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
      ["subb"]=>
      string(8) "foo subb"
    }
  }
}
get_object_vars
------------------------
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(7) "foo sub"
    ["b"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
      ["subb"]=>
      string(8) "foo subb"
    }
  }
}
json_decode+json_encode
------------------------
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["a"]=>
    string(7) "foo sub"
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["subb"]=>
      string(8) "foo subb"
    }
  }
}
[]
------------------------
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["1"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    ["2"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    ["3"]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["a"]=>
      string(7) "foo sub"
      ["b"]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
        ["subb"]=>
        string(8) "foo subb"
      }
    }
  }
}


Suena a pregunta de curso. El OP no muestra ninguna investigación previa ni error... No se yo si la tendriamos que haber respondido o solo comentarla para que el OP busque mejor la solución.  La pregunta es interesante, como muchas otras de este estilo que normalmente votamos para su cierre por no seguir las indicaciones de [ask] y [example].
